# How to represent unconfirmed state?

Tags: web, data-display

I work for an application which have limited output for readability purpose. It has a web ui symbol and text for ok and another for not ok, but here is the thing : sometimes a not ok is due to temporary failure, and the status have to be confirmed or infirmed later on.

What would best UX for displaying in a most explicit way these temporary fails ?

Comment: When you get a temporary failure, do you **wait** until it shows you a confirmed status? Or does it keep retrying with a **brand new request** each time until you receive a confirmed status?

Comment: There is a retry after a time interval, which can be of several minutes. In the meantime i need efficient feedback for the user

Answer (score 1):

If a status isn't confirmed - this is what you suppose to display, isn't?
Consider something in this direction:
Status y: Processing
Status z: INVALID (confirming...)

Comment: I thought about a new state too at first, but the trick is, a fail is a fail, the state is clear but *might be* temporary and this is what i am trying to represent. So in the end it's about wording 'might be temporary' in an understandable way, without random connotation if possible.

Comment: I agree.
p.s. It won't help much but maybe a kind of additional "Confirming" badge or kind of "refreshing" icon (with a tooltip) will inform the user well.